How to short time delay controller?
I have an old keyboard which I use for decorative purpose. It has RGB lights which turns on for few seconds when a key is pressed. I want to keep them on at all times. How to achieve this? Can I simply short a relay or switch present on the PCB. I am completely new to this so do not have much idea. Attaching a picture for reference.


Do the lights stay on if you hold a key down? If not, shorting a key won't work. If so, just go for it.

Unfortunately no. I tried shorting a key, didn't work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can buy an inexpensive module  that produces pulses at an adjustable rate and wire it to a 2N7000 to short a key.

Hey Thanks @SpehroPefhany, got the idea. I was also thinking maybe I could short a key using 555 timer IC. I am not sure though how will it work but I'll figure it out.
Thanks much!

Update: shorting it with a simple pulse generator made with a 555 timer IC worked fine.
